# Primefaces selectOne Radio button not working as required

Tags: jsf

I have a condition where i need to have two radio buttond with related data in the below the buttons.

i did something like below but the selected radio button value is not getting in the backed been. Please correct where i am going wrong

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <h:selectOneRadio  value="#{beenObject.adressSelection}">
 <f:selectItem itemValue="Employer" itemLabel="Employer" />
 </h:selectOneRadio>.
</td>

  <td>
 <h:selectOneRadio value="#{beenObject.adressSelection}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="Consultant" itemLabel="Consultant" />
  </h:selectOneRadio>.

  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <h:outputText value="#{beenObject.consultentDetailsString}">         
  </h:outputText>
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>
  <h:outputText value="#{beenObject.employerDetailsString}">         
  </h:outputText>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: You're not using any PrimeFaces component in your post. Also, make sure all the components are inside the same `<h:form>` than your `UICommand` or that those components are being taken into account when sending the data to server.

Comment: forgot to mention that, yes it is inthe same form tag,and same p:dialog

Comment: This indeed won't work that way because they're not grouped. But first and foremost, why not just `<p:dataTable><p:column selectionMode="single">`?

Comment: @BalusC can you please elaborate.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml - 5th example (titled "RadioButton")

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing an issue similar as yours however I tried to replicate my situation at your code. While I was simplifying the lines I just end-up fixing your bug.

Below the code wich will work for you.

```
     <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{beenObject.adressSelection}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Employer" itemLabel="Employer" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Consultant" itemLabel="Consultant" />
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText value="#{beenObject.consultentDetailsString}">
                    </h:outputText> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{beenObject.employerDetailsString}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Explaining what I did:
I grouped the elements f:selectItem underneath f:selectItems like is shown in the sample at primeface showcase and it starts to work.
Hope it work as you want.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, this is the same as mentioned/suggested in a comment 3.5 years ago, correct?

Comment: Yes, is pretty much the same thing.